# How to allow certain characters in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i allow only "A-Za-z0-9 &#$._-" along with "/" . I tried with jquery

```
$('.allow').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 

   $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 &#$._-]/g,' ') ); }

);
```

Along with this i also need to allow forward slash "/".

Can anyone please help me out. It will be a great help.

Comment: You have the right idea here by checking the field value with a regex, you just have to escape the '/'.

Answer (score 2):

Use `^` and `$` outside of `[]`. This will match only the allowed characters.

You need to escape the `/` and `-` in `regex`

```
/^[a-z0-9 &#$._\-\/]$/i
```

Comment: @mohdilyas If the problem is solved, you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.allow').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 

   $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\\ &#$._-]/g,' ') ); }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="allow"/>
```